# Toolbar disappear when backPressed if collapsed

Tags: android, toolbar, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

My **toolbar** is becoming invisible or disappearing when backPressed. This situation occur only if the **toolbar is collapsed**.

1. I have a RecyclerView on a Fragment
2. When I scroll the recycler the toolbar collapses
3. If I enter on the next activity, called by some of the recycler itens and then press the back button, the toolbar disappear.
4. If I scroll the recycler the collapsing still occurs, but the toolbar isn't there, just a vertical space with nothing on it.

**Fragment Layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <!--Toolbar-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            style="@style/mytoolbar_details"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:background="@color/theme_primary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none" />

    <!--Toolbar Sort-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        style="@style/mytoolbar_details"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_sort"
        android:title="Toolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary_dark"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_tasklist_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

  <!--ADD Fragment Container-->
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Calling the layout on the Fragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fragmentView    = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasklist_fragment, container, false);
```

**Some probable issues**

```
W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{335f934 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-1080,168 #7f0d009c app:id/toolbar} during layout: running second layout pass

W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout{3c2cf991 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-1080,420 #7f0d009a app:id/collapsing_toolbar} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out my code was OK.
The problem was caused by some bug on the appcompat lib. I just updated the support library to the version 22.2.1 and the issue disappeared.

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1"
compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1"
compile "com.android.support:design:22.2.1"
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

it works only with design support library v22.2.1 at the moment
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183333